# Aligning button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to adjust the size of several divs on my page so that they match. Then I would like the align the button at the bottom of the div using `float: bottom`. The height adjustment works fine but I can't seem to figure out why the `.css()` function is not working for me. Here is some example code that illustrates the issue:

HTML:

```
<div class="box" style='border: solid'>
<p> there is text inside this box</p>
<button class="adjust">test Button</button>
</div>

<div class="box" style='border: solid'>
    <p> there is text inside this box</p>
    <p> there is text inside this box</p>
    <p> there is text inside this box</p>
    <button class="adjust">test Button</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $maxh = 0;
            $(".box").each(function(){
                if($(this).height() > $maxh){
                    $maxh = $(this).height();
                }
            });
            $(".box").each(function(){
                $(this).height($maxh);
            });
            $(".adjust").each(function(){
                $(this).css("float", "bottom");
            });
        });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbhronwb/)

Comment: Bottom is not a valid value for float.

Comment: I didn't think so either, but my IDE had it as a valid option, so I went with it. Do you have any suggestions to get the desired result without `float: bottom`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, there is no `float: bottom` attribute in CSS.

In your specific example, you should do something like this:

```
.box { position: relative; }

.box button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This will force your buttons to align to the bottom of their containing div.

Comment: Also, you will likely want to add a `padding-bottom` value of 20px or so to the `.box` class, otherwise you will see an unsightly overlap!

Comment: Thanks, Richard. That works very well except fact that positioning the elements like that does not work will for a responsive design. Adjusting the width of the browser after the page loads throws off the position of the button if they are set up like you suggested. Any ideas for this problem?